# Limit an RSS Feed in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss

This seems like such a simple thing that it isn't worth a question, but I haven't yet found the answer! I am parsing an RSS feed using

```
@rss_industry = RSS::Parser.parse('http://construction.com/rss/construction.xml', false)
```

This brings back the entire feed. I simply want to limit the number of items returned. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless construction.com builds the feed dynamically and gives you the option of limiting it, no.

Comment: `.xml` extension makes me think about this is plain text file, regenerated on the content changes. Besides weird hack with opening raw socket to this server, getting chunks and terminating on superfluous chunk (yeah, just kidding,) there is no way to force remote server to serve a part of the file it has.

Comment: RSS is XML. It's valid to use a .xml extension since it's the content that is important. The .xml is only one part of the name of the resource. And, terminating an XML feed early will only result in corrupted XML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Is there a simple way to do this"? On SO we help you fix your code, but we need to see what you've tried. What's in `@rss_industry`? How are you parsing that structure/object? Typical feeds are a single chunk of all articles and once parsed it's up to you to extract what you want. So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like that's a feature in the [stdlib RSS::Parser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rss/rdoc/RSS.html) class.

There are other ways to parse RSS.

But there's probably no way to avoid *fetching* the entire XML file over HTTP, even if you're only interested in the first X items. And you've fetched it, there's probably no great way to avoid *parsing* the entire XML, even if you only want certain parts of it. There might be *some* complicated way using a streaming XML parser, but unless the XML file is *really* huge, you probably don't want to go down there.

Instead, if you are only interested in the first X items in the feed, why not just only look at those?

```
 feed = RSS::Parser.parse('http://construction.com/rss/construction.xml', false)

 all_items = feed.items
 first_10_items = feed.items.slice(0, 10)
```